# Environment Variables on OS X Lion complete guide?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, environment-variables, environment

I was wondering where people find information about environment variables. I have seen that there are often conflicting and confusing descriptions of how to set environment variables for OS X Lion. I tried searching the Mac Developer library with little luck. Can anyone point me in the right direction? My goal is to get a grasp of the hierarchy and scope of environment variables on OS X Lion.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, doesn't exist. Environment variables are generally associated with individual apps and libraries and so their documentation is found in the docs for those apps and libraries.